# Javascript Validation not Working with Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

My javascript validator is not working. When I input nothing, the alert is not displayed. Additionally, could you guys explain to me what the action method regarding forms is and how I am supposed to use it?

```
<form method = "post" id = "my_form">
        <h1> Thank you for visiting our website! Please take some time to fill out our service questions! </h1>
        <h2> The ratings given are F, D, C, B and A. </h3>
        <h3> How would you rate the service that this webpage provides?? </h3> 
        <input type = "text" font-size = "15px" id = "name">
        <h3> How would you rate the organization and usability of this webpage?? </h3> 
        <input type = "text" font-size = "15px" id = "name">
        <h3> How would you rate the professionalism of this webpage?? </h3> 
        <input type = "text" font-size = "15px" id = "name">
        <h3> How would you rate the overall look of this webpage??</h3> 
        <input type = "text" font-size = "15px" id = "name">
        <br /><br />
        <input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit">
        </form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var my_form = document.getElementById("my_form");
my_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var tomatch = /[a-f]/i;
    if (!tomatch.test(name)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.alert("The name can only contain letters from a-f");
    }
}. false);
</script>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique in HTML. you may need to avoid use `id="name"` 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You have several inputs with same ID, and incorrect syntax error here

```
my_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    // bunch of code...
}. false); // <-- not dot, but comma
```

Check the solution below

```js
document.getElementById("my_form").onsubmit = function(event) {
  var tomatch = /[a-f]/i;

  //var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  // you can also get value like this
  var name = document.forms.my_form.name.value

  if (!tomatch.test(name)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.alert("The name can only contain letters from a-f");
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="my_form" method="post" action"/my-url">
  <input type="text" font-size="15px" id="name">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What happens if I want to add  an action that sends the information to a php document if the user has submitted the right information

Comment: Read docs on html form element, you just need to add action and method attributed to form

Comment: @FranckRaul updated, added action and method attributes

Answer (score 0):

For regular expression use

```
var tomatch = new RegExp("/[a-f]/i");
```

Regards.